# Remember me and session in symfony2

Tags: session, symfony, remember-me

I am storing some information related to logged user in session.
If the user logged with remember me cookie, he didn't get data from the session.
It is normal behavior. My question is how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Store the information in the database.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Do you think the longer the answer the more useful it is? I've answered the question pretty well — provided the details of the question itself.